# Unable to find item created using core service from any other machine except where Tridion CMS is installed

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am not able to find any item (schema/component) created using core service from any other machine except where Tridion CMS is installed, but when I create any item on the machine where I have Tridion CMS  installed using the same console application then I am able to locate that particular item with TCM URI. Is there any configuration need to define in config file (I think this issue is not related with refreshing or clearing browser cache) and also when TCM URI is generated from other machines too, then how that item is not searchable even from where CMS server is installed. Please suggest...

More information:-

I am working on SDL Tridion 2011 GA also below is the sample code of creating a component which I am using:-

```cs
public static string CreateComponentStack(string folderUri, string title,
                                          string schemaID)
{
    core_service.ServiceReference1.SessionAwareCoreService2010Client client = 
        new SessionAwareCoreService2010Client();
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUserName";
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword";
    client.Open();

    ReadOptions readoptions = new ReadOptions();

    string TargetFolderTcmId = folderUri;
    string LinkSchemaTcmId = schemaID;
    ComponentData CurrentMigrationComponent = client.GetDefaultData(
                ItemType.Component, TargetFolderTcmId) as ComponentData;
    LinkToSchemaData SchemaToUse = new LinkToSchemaData();
    SchemaToUse.IdRef = LinkSchemaTcmId.ToString();
    CurrentMigrationComponent.Schema = SchemaToUse;
    CurrentMigrationComponent.Title = title;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.LoadXml("<Content xmlns='uuid:7289aba9-16de-487c-9142-f6f97dbd2571'>"+
                "</Content>");

    CurrentMigrationComponent.Content = doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
    string newTCMID = client.Create(CurrentMigrationComponent, readoptions).Id; 
    Console.WriteLine(CurrentMigrationComponent.Id);
    Console.ReadLine(); 
    return newTCMID; 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The item either exists or it does not. It is not created with any knowledge of a "creation context" that you seem to be experiencing.

Are you sure you created the item in the same publication that you are looking in? Is the item checked-in?

If it's not something like that, I suggest sharing the crucial bits of your code with us: probably the part that creates the connection and sets the user credentials on it (blank out the actual values of course) and the part that calls the `Save`, `Update` or `Create` methods on the `CoreServiceClient`.

***Update***

The code you added looks fine to me. But there are a few things you might want to check about it:

```
string newTCMID = client.Create(CurrentMigrationComponent, readoptions).Id; 
Console.WriteLine(CurrentMigrationComponent.Id);
```

Given that you are ***creating*** a new Component, the `CurrentMigrationComponent` variable with have an `Id` of `tcm:0-0-0`. What value do you get back in `newTCMID`? And if you search for that TCM URI (using the search function in the GUI), does it find anything?

Comment: I have given service reference with server URL for ex:-              http://myServerdomain.com/webservices/CoreService.svc, so there is no point in configuration files refering to localost. I have entered this http://myServerdomain.com in my local machine's host file. AS TCM URI is also generating for all items using the above kind of code from local machine too I am find it difficult ot reach to the solution. Many thanks to  you for replying!

Comment: Yes, I am getting newTCMID value as a new URI but when I seacrh for that URI in Tridion CMS either locally or at server where Tridion is installed error message says:                                                             Item newTCMID doesn't exists but using the same code when I run it on server machine I can find item with whatever newTCMID is generated at that time.

Comment: That seems to indicate that no matter what you believe: the Component was ***not*** created on that Tridion CMS and your local copy is likely talking to another Tridion instance. You can verify that most easily by making your content invalid according to the schema (e.g. changing the namespace or adding an invalid XML element) and seeing the program fail. Once that has happened, you will find an event in the event log of the machine where the create action was executed. My guess is that you won't find that event on the machine where expect it to appear. Other than that: check your endpoint def

Comment: Frank, I have tried to call checkin() as per your suggestion so I have added after create() line following code:-client.CheckIn(newTCMID, readoptions).Id; but when this line executes I am getting an error i.e. "The item is not checked-out.". Also I am not able to create that name item again so it must be creating somewhere. I am trying to implement your last comment, let's see what happens. Many thanks for all your support once again

Comment: I may be overlooking something here, but shouldn't client.Create be followed at some point with client.Save? With the Save commiting the newly created item to the DB?

Comment: @Jeremy: read the docs please "Create(....) - Creates an object, updates it with the given data and saves the state of the object to the database and checks in the item."

Comment: Ok, thanks - I had a feeling it was me overlooking something :)

Comment: Thanks Franks for clarifying and yes Jeremy, I am using either of create() or save () and then I'm calling checkin() (although with create() item checks in automatically).

Comment: Frank, could you please reply what all are the option to check logs of Tridion?

Comment: If you try to create an illegal component, it will fail. You will get an error message on the client and a related error message will show up in the event viewer on your server. If you can't find a relevant error message on the server, that is not where you are trying to create the component on that server. If you want to know which event log to look into, reproduce the same error when running the program on the server itself and you'll be able to find the error event.

Comment: Hi Frank, sorry for late reply. Yes you were right, I am not able to find entry in event viewer when something fails from local machine while on CMS server I am able to find that. But this problem is occuring at all local machine might be this is configuration issue, could you please suggest I have following entry in app.config, is this coorect?                   <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>              or should I replace localhost with my domain, please reply

Comment: Also we had an another instance which we are not using (it is down) right now but coreservice URL for both the instances is same and I have tried on some other local machine from which I have never access old instance coreservice URL but on that machine too this problem reproduce.

Comment: The answer remains the same as before: when you run the program from your local machine, you clearly end up creating the Component on a different Tridion server than you expect. There isn't a lot more I can do for you.

Comment: I agree with you but as we don't have any other instance so I'm unable to figure it out. Anyways many thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 3):

When you say "other machines" do you mean other severs running the core service client console app?  Check that the machines are in the same network domain and that you can connect to Tridion from them.  Also check if there are any network policy restrictions preventing outgoing http requests on server machines.

It would help if you provide the error output you get.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the section in your app.config file, may be your endpoint your map to localhost.

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://[ur]/webservices/CoreService.svc/basicHttp_2010"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp_2010"
                contract="CoreService.ICoreService2010" name="basicHttp_2010" />
            <endpoint address="http://[ur]/webservices/CoreService.svc/streamDownload_basicHttp_2010"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamDownload_basicHttp_2010"
                contract="CoreService.IStreamDownload2010" name="streamDownload_basicHttp_2010" />
            <endpoint address="http://[ur]/webservices/CoreService.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp_2010"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamUpload_basicHttp_2010"
                contract="CoreService.IStreamUpload2010" name="streamUpload_basicHttp_2010" />
            <endpoint address="http://[ur]/webservices/CoreService.svc/wsHttp_2010"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp_2010"
                contract="CoreService.ISessionAwareCoreService2010" name="wsHttp_2010">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
```

Comment: Except in dns like your sample config, I don't have "localhost" as value any where else, please suggest do I need to change dns value if yes then to what? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the database, whether the item exists or not?