# Is there any limitation in using core service through VM

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm creating component etc using Core service but I'm creating them using VM rather than actual server where Tridion server is installed. The issue I'm facing is I am unable to track the item created on VM even when TCM id is generated for them also when I create any item through UI then I can track them on VM. So is there any limitation when we create any item using core service through VM? As our servers is in other geo location, so IS there a way to track the IP where core service is creating the component so that I can assume my code will work fine on production server. Some more information:-

> I am able to access core service.svc file through browser.
>   Event Viewer is not showing any error/warning message if item creation fails through core service.

Please suggest...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find item created using core service from any other machine except where Tridion CMS is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176679/unable-to-find-item-created-using-core-service-from-any-other-machine-except-whe)

Comment: I mostly use local VM for dev work, and never had any issues with Core Service. Not sure what you mean with "vm rather than actual server" - a VM can be a server.

Comment: Same here, although in my case I most often work with remote VMs on either an ESX or on Amazon. The only times I have problems is if I have a host name mapped incorrectly in my local `hosts` file, which really has **nothing** to do with Tridion or its Core Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though fiddler setting in app.config file and run the fiddler and then you can debug the code and check which request is going to tridion and which request is coming from tridion

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888"
             bypassonlocal="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Your reply answers my question. Thanks a lot and sorry for late reply as I was busy with other project's tasks. One more thing it worked with just giving proxy's address in app.config but what is fiddler is that a tool of SDL?